# Is it possible to isolate an eigenvalue for a general case with the equation $A\mathbf{x} = \lambda_i\mathbf{x}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I know the derivation is probably online in a lot of places; but perhaps I'm wording my question wrong, I cannot find an example online that satisfies what I am looking for.

My question is given a $n \ x \ n$ symmetric matrix, what would be the generalization to isolate $\lambda_i$ from $A\mathbf{x} = \lambda_i\mathbf{x}$ to $\lambda_i$ = ...

Most examples I've seen either used Spectral theorem or the values of matrix and eigenvectors are already given, is there an intuitive explanation to this question?

Answer (score 1):

Take the equation and multiply by $\mathbf{x}^T$ (normalized), then $\mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x} = \lambda_i \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x} = \lambda_i$

**Note** Scalar-vector multiplication is commutative

\begin{equation}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x_1 & x_2
\end{matrix}
\right]
\lambda_i
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\lambda_i x_1 & \lambda_i x_2
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\lambda_i
\left[
\begin{matrix}
 x_1 & x_2
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{matrix}
\right]
\end{equation}

**General idea**

Suppose $A$ has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2, \dots, \mathbf{x}_n$ corresponding to distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1>\lambda_2>\cdots>\lambda_n >0$.

Every unit vector $\mathbf{x}$ has an expansion $\mathbf{x} = \sum \alpha_i \mathbf{x}_i$, where $\sum \alpha_i^2 = 1$.

Then $A\mathbf{x} = \sum \alpha_i A\mathbf{x}_i = \sum \alpha_i \lambda_i\mathbf{x}_i$ and $\mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x}= \sum \alpha_i^2 \lambda_i$

The maximum value of this expression occurs when $\alpha_1=1$ and all other $\alpha_i$ are 0. If we restrict to the complement of $\mathbf{x}_1$ (i.e. requiring $\alpha_1=0$), then the max occurs for $\alpha_2 = 1$, etc.

Comment: I thought about this, but this is different from $\lambda_i x \cdot x^T$? How would you change from $\lambda_i x \cdot x^T$ to $\lambda_i x^T \cdot x$?

Comment: If you want to isolate $\lambda_i$, you want to multiply on the left not the right.

Comment: And how would you the eigenvector $\mathbf{x}$ differ for each $i\in(1,...,n)$ for $\lambda_i$? Is there a way to generalize this?

Comment: Perhaps the question is not very clear. Are you looking for the Courant Fisher  theorem?

Comment: I don't really understand. If I multiply from the left side, it would still give me $x^TAx = x^T\lambda_i x$. And yes! But i'm having trouble understanding that definition, so I'm trying to break it down from the basic eigenvalue-vector equation.

Comment: Ok, now I know the name of the theorem, it helps a lot. Thank you. However, I am still confused about how $x^TAx = x^T\lambda_i x$ works.